# PHP can't call API from FastAPI

Tags: python, php, api, rest, fastapi

I built an API with FastAPI, then I want to call it by PHP (I ran PHP  by Docker, expose port 80 to 80), but It give always boolean(False).
However this API works very well with JavaScript, Postman, Firefox.(I want to give results from this API to externals users so my ideal is using PHP to bring the results from this API, then give it to Front-end, I don't know how to give this API directly from FastAPI to externals users).
So you can see my code for FastAPI below:

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI #import class FastAPI() from library fastapi
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    import main_user
    import user_database
    from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
    app = FastAPI() #constructor and  app

    origins = [
       "http://localhost",
       "http://localhost:80",
       "https://localhost",
       "https://localhost:80"
   ]
   app.add_middleware(
       CORSMiddleware,
       allow_origins=['*'],
       allow_credentials=True,
       allow_methods=["*"],
       allow_headers=["*"],
   )

   class InfosCalculIndice(BaseModel):
       nomTuile:str
       dateAcquisition:str
       heureAcquisition:str
       nomIndice:str
       lonMin: float
       lonMax: float
       latMin: float
       latMax: float
       interp: str
       imgFormat: str
   class InfosLogin(BaseModel):
       username: str
       password: str
   class InfosTuile(BaseModel):
       tuile:str

   @app.post("/calcul-indice")
   async def calcul_indice(infos: InfosCalculIndice):
       img = main_user.calcul_api(infos.nomTuile,                                                                                            infos.dateAcquisition,infos.nomIndice,infos.lonMin,
       infos.lonMax,infos.latMin,infos.latMax,infos.interp, infos.imgFormat)
       return {"img":img}
   @app.post("/login")
   async def login(infos: InfosLogin):
       status = user_database.login(infos.username, infos.password)
       return {"stt":status}
   @app.post("/register")
   async def register(infos: InfosLogin):
       stt = user_database.createUser(infos.username, infos.password)
       return {"stt":stt}
   @app.get("/get-tuile")
   async def getTuile():
       tuiles = user_database.getAllTuiles()
       return tuiles
```

And here is code in PHP:

```
    <?php

    $url = 'http://localhost/login'; #OR http://127.0.0.1:800/login
    $data = array("username" => "myusernam", "password"=>"mypassword");
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8000); #OR without this option
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // For HTTPS
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // For HTTPS
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
   'Content-Type: application/json', 'server:uvicorn'
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $response;
    var_dump($response);
    curl_close($curl);
    ?>
```

I also tried with `file_get_contents` but not thing changed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you get error message when you run PHP ? Do you get any error message in FastAPI? Do you write anything in log file to see what you get?  You could use even Flask to build Front-End. OR pure HTML with JavaScript (directly or with ie. React, Vue). As I know exposed port is used to access PHP from outside, not to access outside from PHP. And I'm not sure if docker use `localhost` as IP. It may use something from subnet `172.17.0.0/16`

Comment: Thank you @furas, by your suggestion, I found the solution. The PHP on docker container can't access to host port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution, curl on php on docker can't call the api from host with ip 127.0.0.1.
I use command `ip addr show docker0` then I take the inet address instead of localhost, and It worked.